# Convert postgresql hstore to php array

Tags: php, postgresql

Is there a good php code snippet to convert a postgresql hstore to a php array, that will correctly translate an unquoted NULL within the hstore to a php NULL?

EG: Suppose we have the following hstore string:

```
"k1"=>"v1", "k2"=>NULL, "k3"=>"NULL", "k4"=>"\"v4"
(aka SELECT '"k1"=>"v1","k2"=>NULL,"k3"=>"NULL","k4"=>"\\"v4"'::hstore;)
```

How can we convert this into the following php array?

array('k1' => 'v1', 'k2' => NULL, 'k3' => 'NULL', 'k4' => '\"v4');

I following the following converter but it does not seem to handle the unquoted NULL: https://github.com/chanmix51/Pomm/blob/master/Pomm/Converter/PgHStore.php

Answer (score 5):

I believe the syntax would be something like this:

```
$pdo = new PDO( /*connection string*/ );
// h is the hstore column.
$stmt = $pdo->query( "SELECT (each(h)).key, (each(h)).value FROM <table name>" );
$output = array();
foreach( $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_NUM ) as $row )
{
   // $row[ 0 ] is the key, $row[ 1 ] is the value.
   $output[ $row[ 0 ] ] = $row[ 1 ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and it should work when retrieving the hstore directly from the db. Unfortunately, the primary use case here is that I have the hstore value passed to a class from an external api (that I am not able to change) as a method input argument, so I need a 100% php (no callouts to postgresql server via pdo) to parse the hstore and convert into a php array.

Comment: There is easier way to make `key / value` pair from query result without walking through - `PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR`;

Comment: this is definitely the best way to handle hstores in PHP. very unfortunate, huge waste of line congestion, but the only truly reliable solution i've found.

Answer (score 2):

```php
$hstore = '"A"=>"AAA", "B"=>"BBB"';
print_r(json_decode('{' . str_replace('"=>"', '":"', $hstore) . '}', true));
```

Comment: There is one problem I've noticed with using json_encode() and json_decode(). First, the JSON spec does not allow for the [tab] character. While PHP's json_encode() ignores and allows for tab characters just fine, when you attempt to then run the JSON-encoded string through json_decode(), a mal-formed JSON error occurs, and the function returns an empty string.

Comment: in addition, hstore allows for NULL values. if you're searching for `"=>"', hstores with NULL values will not be handled correctly. Eg: `"key1"=>"val1","key2"=>NULL` would be incorrectly converted into `"key1":"val1","key2"=>NULL`

Answer (score 2):

I attempted to make use of Pomm's PgHStore method, however it broke under a half dozen or so different circumstances. I don't remember them all, but here are a few I do recall:

- Lack of native PHP Null support
- Lack of properly escaping double quotes
- Didn't properly escape values for safe PostgreSQL insertion

I ultimately ended up deriving my own solution, coined PHPG. Supports automatic conversion of arrays of any data-type, Hstores, Geometric data-types, Dates / Timestamps, etc: https://github.com/JDBurnZ/PHPG

If you wish to tackle this problem without the use of an external class or library, this is going to be *very* difficult and will most likely be reliable, and here's why:

One might suggest you could simply explode on `","` to create a list of key/value pairs, from which you could explode each element in the list on `"=>"`. This works if *all* values are strings, but PostgreSQL Hstores support NULL values. NULL values are not encapsulated in double quotes, so the above solution will not work appropriately in these scenarios.

Comment: Hi. This looks promising, but is there any actual code to be had?

Comment: There is now, feel free to check it out and let me know what you think.

Comment: Not really suitable for me after all, since it uses its own "proprietary" connection. I can't replace all my PDO based code with it. I'd have hoped for a simple standalone value parser instead of a complete connection package.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case somebody is still interested in this: since 9.2 there is a function called hstore_to_json that can be used in select clauses to convert the hstore content to JSON. This will look like this:

```
SELECT id, hstore_to_json(my_hstore_field) AS myField FROM mytable WHERE ...
```

Then in PHP just use

```
json_decode($row['myField'])
```

to decode it to a php array...

Answer (score 1):

Since none of the other solutions seem to be working perfectly, I ended up with a rather conservative two-part approach:

```
protected function toPostgresHStoreLiteral(array $array) {
    return join(',', F\map($array, function ($value, $key) {
        switch (strtolower(gettype($value))) {
            case 'null' :
            case 'boolean' :
                $value = $value ? 'true' : '';
                break;

            case 'object' :
                if (!is_callable([$value, '__toString'])) {
                    throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Cannot cast object of type %s to string', get_class($value)));
                }
                // deliberate fallthrough
            case 'integer' :
            case 'double' :
            case 'string' :
                settype($value, 'string');
                break;

            default :
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Cannot store values of type %s in an hstore', gettype($value)));
        }

        return call_user_func_array('sprintf', array_reduce(
            [$key, $value],
            function (array $args, $value) { return array_merge($args, [sprintf('"%s"', addcslashes($value, '"\\'))]); },
            ['%s=>%s']
        ));
    }));
}
```

This method formats an array into an hstore literal string ready to be inserted into a query. It may be a little more functional in style than necessary, sorry for that. ^_^;; Depends on PHP 5.4+ and [functional-php](https://github.com/lstrojny/functional-php).

To get hstore values out of Postgres, I'm using JSON as the middle man:

```
SELECT array_to_json(hstore_to_array(value)) AS value ...
```

This gets a JSON encoded array which can be turned into a regular PHP array using this:

```
protected function postgresJsonHstoreToArray($json) {
    $values = json_decode($json, true);
    $array  = [];

    for ($i = 0, $length = count($values); $i < $length; $i++) {
        $key   = $values[$i];
        $value = $values[++$i];
        $array[$key] = $value;
    }

    return $array;
}
```

This depends on Postgres 9.2+ or 9.1 with the [json_91](https://bitbucket.org/adunstan/json_91) backport.

This is copied straight out of some custom code, not necessarily very generalized, but it has withstood some realworld usage already.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem myself, so I came up with the following solution:

```
function hstore2array($data) {
    preg_match_all('/(?:"((?:\\\\"|[^"])+)"|(\w+))\s*=>\s*(?:"((?:\\\\"|[^"])*)"|(NULL))/ms',
        $data, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    $hstore = array();
    foreach ($matches as $set) {
        $key = $set[1] ? $set[1] : $set[2];
        $val = $set[4]=='NULL' ? null : $set[3];
        $hstore[$key] = $val;
    }
    return $hstore;
}
```

It would properly recognize the following string:

```
"a"=>"1", "b"=>"", "c"=>NULL, "d"=>"Some \"quoted\" value"
```

Answer (score 0):

Pomm's HStore converter has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Usage:

hstore(<some_array_or_object>, false) converts the input to a valid hStore string literal and returns it:

```
hstore(array('k1' => 'v1', 'k2' => 'v2')) => "k1"=>"v1","k2"=>"v2"
```

hstore(<some_array_or_object>) converts the input to a valid hStore, single-quoted, followed by ::hstore

```
hstore(array('k1' => 'v1', 'k2' => 'v2')) => '"k1"=>"v1","k2"=>"v2"'::hstore
```

hstore(<some_string>) converts from an hstore string (as it comes from a query) to array

```
hstore('"k1"=>"v1","k2"=>"v2"') => array('k1' => 'v1', 'k2' => 'v2')
```

It handles NULLs (both ways), and properly escapes/unescapes keys and values.

```
<?php


/**
 * mixed hstore(mixed $input[, bool $prepared = false])
 *      Convert from hstore string to array, or from array/object to hstore.
 * Inner arrays/objects are serialized but deserialization is up to you; you
 * are expected to keep track of which fields you sent as non-scalars.
 *
 * @param mixed $input          A string (from hstore) or an array/object
 * @param type $prepared        Array or object to convert to hstore string
 * @return mixed                Depends on the input
 */
function hstore($input, $prepared=false)
{
    if (is_string($input))
    {
        if ($input === 'NULL')
        {
            $output = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
        $re = '_("|^)(.*?[^\\\\"])"=>"(.*?[^\\\\"])("|$)_s';
        preg_match_all($re, $input, $pairs);
        $mid = $pairs ? array_combine($pairs[2], $pairs[3]) : array();

            foreach ($mid as $k => $v)
            {
                $output[trim($k, '"')] = stripslashes($v);
            }
        }
    }
    elseif (is_null($input))
    {
        $output = $prepared  ? 'NULL::hstore' : 'NULL';
    }
    elseif (!is_scalar($input))
    {
        foreach ((array)$input as $k => $v)
        {
            !is_scalar($v) && ($v = serialize($v));
            $entries[] = '"' . addslashes($k) . '"=>' .
                         '"' . addslashes($v) . '"';
        }

        $mid = empty($entries) ? '' : join(', ', $entries);

        $output = $prepared ? "'{$mid}'::hstore" : $mid;
    }

    return $output;
}

?>
```

edit: added 's' switch to the regex, to correctly handle linefeed within keys or values

Comment: I've tried this and it behaves rather buggy. Parsing doesn't work in all cases with contained quotes and encoding turns `false` into `N;`, which is pretty unexpected. Not a production ready solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
<?php
function encode_hstore($array) {
    if (!$array)
        return NULL;

    if (!is_array($array))
        return $array;

    $expr = array();

    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
        $search = array('\\', "'", '"');
        $replace = array('\\\\', "''", '\"');

        $key = str_replace($search, $replace, $key);
        $val = $val === NULL
             ? 'NULL'
             : '"'.str_replace($search, $replace, $val).'"';

        $expr[] = sprintf('"%s"=>%s', $key, $val);
    }

    return sprintf("'%s'::hstore", implode(',', $expr));
}

function decode_hstore($hstore) {
    if (!$hstore || !preg_match_all('/"(.+)(?<!\\\)"=>(""|NULL|".+(?<!\\\)"),?/U', $hstore, $match, PREG_SET_ORDER))
        return array();

    $array = array();

    foreach ($match as $set) {
        list(, $k, $v) = $set;

        $v = $v === 'NULL'
           ? NULL
           : substr($v, 1, -1);

        $search = array('\"', '\\\\');
        $replace = array('"', '\\');

        $k = str_replace($search, $replace, $k);
        if ($v !== NULL)
            $v = str_replace($search, $replace, $v);

        $array[$k] = $v;
    }

    return $array;
}

$dsn = 'pgsql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test';
$user = 'user';
$pass = 'pass';
$pdo = new \PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);

$data = array(
    'k1' => 'v1',
    'k2' => NULL,
    'k3' => 'NULL',
    'k4' => '"v4',
    'k5' => 'a\'b"c\\d,e',
    'k6' => '"k1"=>"v1", ',
    'k7"=>' => 'v7',
    'k8' => '',
);
var_dump($data);

$expr = encode_hstore($data);
echo $expr . PHP_EOL;

$encoded = $pdo->query("select {$expr}")->fetchColumn();
echo $encoded . PHP_EOL;

$decoded = decode_hstore($encoded);
var_dump($decoded);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
function convertHstoreToArray($hstoreString) {
    $hstoreArray = array();
    // explode array elements
    $keyValueStringsArray = explode(', ', $hstoreString);
    foreach($keyValueStringsArray as $keyValueString) {
        // trim first and last "
        $keyValueString = substr($keyValueString, 1, -1);
        // explode key and value
        $keyValueArray = explode('"=>"', $keyValueString);
        $hstoreArray[$keyValueArray[0]] = $keyValueArray[1];
    }
    return $hstoreArray;
}
```

or

```
function convertHstoreToArray($hstoreString) {
    $hstoreArray = array();
    // explode array elements
    $keyValueStringsArray = explode(', ', $hstoreString);
    foreach($keyValueStringsArray as $keyValueString) {
        // explode key and value
        $keyValueArray = explode('=>', $keyValueString);
        $key = $keyValueArray[0];
        // trim first and last "
        $key = substr($key, 1, -1);
        $value = $keyValueArray[1];
        if ($value === 'NULL') {
            $value = null;
        } else {
            // trim first and last "
            $value = substr($value, 1, -1);
        }
        $hstoreArray[$key] = $value;
    }
    return $hstoreArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to convert a string in PHP (not in db request) you can use following prepared statement (inspired by cwallenpoole's solution):

`select (each(h)).key, (each(h)).value from (select ?::hstore as h) as s`

You can use any PHP variable in this query:

`$st = $db->prepare("select (each(h)).key, (each(h)).value from (select ?::hstore as h) as s");
$st->execute(array('"abc"=>"123", "def"=>"654"');
$out = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);`